# Standard green glass reflection and absorption rates by wavelength

Tags: reflection, wavelength, absorption

Is there any exact data on reflection and absorption rates based on wavelength for the common green glass materials ?

I know the rate itself is dependent of the angle, the exact composition of the glass, and for the green glass averages at about 8%, but that is for the full spectrum of light.

I am interested in specific rates at different wavelengths: IR, Red, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue, Purple, and the UVs. As example, let's assume the standard green glass would reflect 15% green and 3% of blue light -- those are the things of interest.

I cannot currently test this for myself. Is there any research data on this ?

Comment: There may be data available on the internet.  Have you done a search?  What search terms did you use?

Comment: I did, I could only find the specific average rate which is around 8%, but that does not help my research. I submitted a request to a lab that can test this, but the researcher in charge of the equipment is out of the country for 2 moths or so.

Comment: Are you in a university?  Can you take the glass to your Chemistry dept?  They are likely to have a spectro-photometer to measure this.

Comment: I have have some friends at a private lab where they do have a spectro-photometer and other similar devices, but those cannot be used at the moment, until the lead researcher gets back. They have very strict rules.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably have to know the composition of your "standard glass" to get an idea of the spectrum.

Even then it'd be difficult to find any literature specifically related to your glass.

If, for example, your sample is a beer bottle or something like that then the manufacturer would surely have that data but might not make it available.

It is totally dependent on what exactly your "standard green glass" is.

If you can, provide some more details so we might better help you.  Even a general idea of the composition would help approximate the spectrum

Comment: "Standard green glass" as in the one used in normal windows since hundreds of years.

Comment: @Overmid : Standard glass as used in windows?  Then there should be data on the large glass-makers' websites - Pilkington, Schott, Saint-Gobain, etc.  However, I have never seen green-tinted windows.  Bottles yes, windows no.

Comment: They are all green, just not enough for the human eye to notice. Look at a small piece of one.